# Mongo geoJSON corrupted polygon

Tags: python, mongodb, geojson

Im searching in the MongoDB by using a GEOJSON polygon without holes. I get an error when accesing the cursor. The error is:
OperationFailure: Secondary loops not contained by first exterior loop - secondary loops must be holes.

Code:

```
import pymongo
import json

def loadjson(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        mydict = json.load(f)
    return mydict

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' \
                                    + 'username' \
                                    + ':' \
                                    + "password" + \
                                    '@localhost:num')

gjOr=loadjson('polygon.json')

database = client.database
collection = database["name"]
filParam = {"field": {"$geoWithin": {"$geometry": gjOr["geometry"]}}}
exParam = {"parameter": 1} 

cursorItineraries = collection.find(filParam, exParam).batch_size(2)
for i in cursorItineraries:
    print(i)
```

Error :

```
OperationFailure: Secondary loops not contained by first exterior loop - secondary loops must be holes: [ [ 4.423298831017474, 45.92246510136637 ], [ 4.423272328729544, 45.9224124914541 ], [ 4.423296014293201, 45.92245885344253 ], [ 4.423298831017474, 45.92246510136637 ] ] first loop: [ [ 45.80122758057101, 4.376352681950241 ], [ 45.8044838524037, 4.376220111724892 ], [ 45.80502003601278, 4.384299007716068 ], [ 45.80303745929081, 4.388437890276315 ], [ 45.81747689026152, 4.380885175476993 ], [ 45.82029916312589, 4.38306756294014 ], [ 45.82485210019716, 4.37663747923372 ], [ 45.82534211272147, 4.381172591846549 ], [ 45.83402693020424, 4.384295932265717 ], [ 45.83750180635732, 4.391204268525621 ], [ 45.83984258047744, 4.387611887543129 ], [ 45.84600085935993, 4.383682442715087 ], [ 45.85031045846961, 4.391211993814656 ], [ 45.85985548506667, 4.396744466054351 ], [ 45.8651960481546, 4.395075656820409 ], [ 45.86464844812487, 4.390221929905438 ], [ 45.86619589736199, 4.361702458243602 ], [ 45.87693527428829, 4.343076054047009 ], [ 45.88006074780913, 4.340914771281566 ], [ 45.8901897554254, 4.337545959836689 ], [ 45.89739332872952, 4.326829637196063 ], [ 45.90391638987086, 4.32382549599472 ], [ 45.905667965693, 4.327990843251258 ], [ 45.91579311238129, 4.346817863136088 ], [ 45.91668891008069, 4.342257953265195 ], [ 45.9216251460626, 4.338982596932619 ], [ 45.92997139286699, 4.346628121156797 ], [ 45.93185900371628, 4.337155914633498 ], [ 45.94115045303277, 4.322661854063225 ], [ 45.9423274157955, 4.313001397538913 ], [ 45.95343445337902, 4.294525894838753 ], [ 45.95835570732176, 4.301188120177739 ], [ 45.9732026997347, 4.289431726797376 ], [ 45.97782302017173, 4.276356808225782 ], [ 45.97999822296752, 4.273060858987787 ], [ 45.98120074142516, 4.259590688670001 ], [ 45.98675497867428, 4.248658637365085 ], [ 45.99308572400004, 4.247947359178051 ], [ 45.99614759409149, 4.246662259181909 ], [ 45.99563177014321, 4.251765125404147 ], [ 45.99854856923263, 4.265285854935993 ], [ 45.99274541001228, 4.270233183990548 ], [ 45.99239729542708, 4.275045816032846 ], [ 45.99568744605374, 4.289609476470726 ], [ 45.98892048061472, 4.300698529315564 ], [ 45.99439301256719, 4.304534538221632 ], [ 46.0051569133273, 4.31261301303475 ], [ 46.00804632488756, 4.310942716001039 ], [ 46.01128401825687, 4.308859856852684 ], [ 46.02162453052691, 4.306458712603317 ], [ 46.0215031603917, 4.305677962950914 ], [ 46.02080232740203, 4.301223173083229 ], [ 46.01839338755868, 4.288344635543249 ], [ 46.0218025518577, 4.28062738017141 ], [ 46.02393104466132, 4.276598681060639 ], [ 46.03355588764234, 4.270436612377799 ], [ 46.03608569278646, 4.261172108339184 ], [ 46.03914954925174, 4.261574439856753 ], [ 46.04921372290215, 4.251694718008523 ], [ 46.05182172309517, 4.254034942879366 ], [ 46.05394712145236, 4.25770790411945 ], [ 46.05200674707666, 4.266837389513737 ], [ 46.05371908926419, 4.285713698620556 ], [ 46.06348629342862, 4.297946350027559 ], [ 46.06607892681861, 4.300652169094047 ], [ 46.07849083960166, 4.302039193299913 ], [ 46.07922531473847, 4.305599848572079 ], [ 46.08175515713837, 4.311015193331216 ], [ 46.08505691781212, 4.310620920782156 ], [ 46.09488700704484, 4.311938135622067 ], [ 46.10036561585792, 4.306608118283756 ], [ 46.11003344270973, 4.30990269743367 ], [ 46.11227779249233, 4.313417891784874 ], [ 46.11685288921163, 4.320328061893218 ], [ 46.13001463483668, 4.322725351722958 ], [ 46.13326362593953, 4.330293102924566 ], [ 46.13554160597837, 4.333348440257132 ], [ 46.13830957901551, 4.357233936672898 ], [ 46.13849351079732, 4.362195204890961 ], [ 46.1498366233474, 4.377795652104825 ], [ 46.14969360157965, 4.382423398963222 ], [ 46.14767758414561, 4.386051143732711 ], [ 46.13709181954217, 4.408851926159123 ], [ 46.13594976925808, 4.417961239075054 ], [ 46.15142016044436, 4.424267792344496 ], [ 46.15560425283834, 4.431770589521594 ], [ 46.16791483778646, 4.439193639737003 ], [ 46.16998904853596, 4.435772060175736 ], [ 46.18010788550735, 4.414915433192237 ], [ 46.18156481929947, 4.411150008217347 ], [ 46.18227866102438, 4.406966209179808 ], [ 46.18456671088968, 4.403509174410789 ], [ 46.18925424643544, 4.396783755671023 ], [ 46.19570191957066, 4.39747939068123 ], [ 46.20316836045577, 4.423571836902974 ], [ 46.20706171749928, 4.422359640985007 ], [ 46.21010077361071, 4.420471659265854 ], [ 46.21965844746768, 4.407356367902624 ], [ 46.21982737938801, 4.388683312501862 ], [ 46.22571105646608, 4.386829907900418 ], [ 46.23755075963317, 4.39209447339758 ], [ 46.24354546160409, 4.388785758384324 ], [ 46.24619830411654, 4.386173183144986 ], [ 46.24794900440396, 4.38889827660288 ], [ 46.2643415894465, 4.393582057210332 ], [ 46.26655827183746, 4.397449686073675 ], [ 46.27187809126278, 4.397064201352286 ], [ 46.27457798360896, 4.396974174839016 ], [ 46.28435539290889, 4.399371429518632 ], [ 46.29277972056357, 4.407707294944299 ], [ 46.29609636649197, 4.406422030172297 ], [ 46.29537513021594, 4.411216732267508 ], [ 46.29633635905063, 4.424994132856644 ], [ 46.30286120593534, 4.427650449880751 ], [ 46.29631496657498, 4.438330372797787 ], [ 46.29309133554136, 4.440062626728649 ], [ 46.29647617285935, 4.453855067913997 ], [ 46.29405157990985, 4.46279605745037 ], [ 46.28443417433566, 4.47602647504644 ], [ 46.28709961733546, 4.484382424854218 ], [ 46.28803138168911, 4.489069361733742 ], [ 46.27010728719618, 4.50209226866315 ], [ 46.26716933623024, 4.504596974106646 ], [ 46.2719961499778, 4.542944499553459 ], [ 46.27395480446275, 4.547049893978835 ], [ 46.2832619806662, 4.548685286189365 ], [ 46.29129615541792, 4.556044471210963 ], [ 46.29402942721709, 4.55844617134213 ], [ 46.29306430926767, 4.570871194910193 ], [ 46.29001185910924, 4.572758405594865 ], [ 46.27707566137231, 4.573323169325609 ], [ 46.27025349602457, 4.58326888257721 ], [ 46.26839674289919, 4.587119484978682 ], [ 46.26643179980633, 4.615050419767011 ], [ 46.2654086056003, 4.617672483965549 ], [ 45.80592709186426, 4.865072663474678 ], [ 45.80434184846744, 4.864499321786514 ], [ 45.80433950695036, 4.864498347340356 ], [ 45.80545594864911, 4.848595888972264 ], [ 45.76435319429793, 4.801430760920382 ], [ 45.71917418711324, 4.781774751613478 ], [ 45.68363470756887, 4.80870542554455 ], [ 45.80122758057101, 4.376352681950241 ] ], full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Secondary loops not contained by first exterior loop - secondary loops must be holes: [ [ 4.423298831017474, 45.92246510136637 ], [ 4.423272328729544, 45.9224124914541 ], [ 4.423296014293201, 45.92245885344253 ], [ 4.423298831017474, 45.92246510136637 ] ] first loop: [ [ 45.80122758057101, 4.376352681950241 ], [ 45.8044838524037, 4.376220111724892 ], [ 45.80502003601278, 4.384299007716068 ], [ 45.80303745929081, 4.388437890276315 ], [ 45.81747689026152, 4.380885175476993 ], [ 45.82029916312589, 4.38306756294014 ], [ 45.82485210019716, 4.37663747923372 ], [ 45.82534211272147, 4.381172591846549 ], [ 45.83402693020424, 4.384295932265717 ], [ 45.83750180635732, 4.391204268525621 ], [ 45.83984258047744, 4.387611887543129 ], [ 45.84600085935993, 4.383682442715087 ], [ 45.85031045846961, 4.391211993814656 ], [ 45.85985548506667, 4.396744466054351 ], [ 45.8651960481546, 4.395075656820409 ], [ 45.86464844812487, 4.390221929905438 ], [ 45.86619589736199, 4.361702458243602 ], [ 45.87693527428829, 4.343076054047009 ], [ 45.88006074780913, 4.340914771281566 ], [ 45.8901897554254, 4.337545959836689 ], [ 45.89739332872952, 4.326829637196063 ], [ 45.90391638987086, 4.32382549599472 ], [ 45.905667965693, 4.327990843251258 ], [ 45.91579311238129, 4.346817863136088 ], [ 45.91668891008069, 4.342257953265195 ], [ 45.9216251460626, 4.338982596932619 ], [ 45.92997139286699, 4.346628121156797 ], [ 45.93185900371628, 4.337155914633498 ], [ 45.94115045303277, 4.322661854063225 ], [ 45.9423274157955, 4.313001397538913 ], [ 45.95343445337902, 4.294525894838753 ], [ 45.95835570732176, 4.301188120177739 ], [ 45.9732026997347, 4.289431726797376 ], [ 45.97782302017173, 4.276356808225782 ], [ 45.97999822296752, 4.273060858987787 ], [ 45.98120074142516, 4.259590688670001 ], [ 45.98675497867428, 4.248658637365085 ], [ 45.99308572400004, 4.247947359178051 ], [ 45.99614759409149, 4.246662259181909 ], [ 45.99563177014321, 4.251765125404147 ], [ 45.99854856923263, 4.265285854935993 ], [ 45.99274541001228, 4.270233183990548 ], [ 45.99239729542708, 4.275045816032846 ], [ 45.99568744605374, 4.289609476470726 ], [ 45.98892048061472, 4.300698529315564 ], [ 45.99439301256719, 4.304534538221632 ], [ 46.0051569133273, 4.31261301303475 ], [ 46.00804632488756, 4.310942716001039 ], [ 46.01128401825687, 4.308859856852684 ], [ 46.02162453052691, 4.306458712603317 ], [ 46.0215031603917, 4.305677962950914 ], [ 46.02080232740203, 4.301223173083229 ], [ 46.01839338755868, 4.288344635543249 ], [ 46.0218025518577, 4.28062738017141 ], [ 46.02393104466132, 4.276598681060639 ], [ 46.03355588764234, 4.270436612377799 ], [ 46.03608569278646, 4.261172108339184 ], [ 46.03914954925174, 4.261574439856753 ], [ 46.04921372290215, 4.251694718008523 ], [ 46.05182172309517, 4.254034942879366 ], [ 46.05394712145236, 4.25770790411945 ], [ 46.05200674707666, 4.266837389513737 ], [ 46.05371908926419, 4.285713698620556 ], [ 46.06348629342862, 4.297946350027559 ], [ 46.06607892681861, 4.300652169094047 ], [ 46.07849083960166, 4.302039193299913 ], [ 46.07922531473847, 4.305599848572079 ], [ 46.08175515713837, 4.311015193331216 ], [ 46.08505691781212, 4.310620920782156 ], [ 46.09488700704484, 4.311938135622067 ], [ 46.10036561585792, 4.306608118283756 ], [ 46.11003344270973, 4.30990269743367 ], [ 46.11227779249233, 4.313417891784874 ], [ 46.11685288921163, 4.320328061893218 ], [ 46.13001463483668, 4.322725351722958 ], [ 46.13326362593953, 4.330293102924566 ], [ 46.13554160597837, 4.333348440257132 ], [ 46.13830957901551, 4.357233936672898 ], [ 46.13849351079732, 4.362195204890961 ], [ 46.1498366233474, 4.377795652104825 ], [ 46.14969360157965, 4.382423398963222 ], [ 46.14767758414561, 4.386051143732711 ], [ 46.13709181954217, 4.408851926159123 ], [ 46.13594976925808, 4.417961239075054 ], [ 46.15142016044436, 4.424267792344496 ], [ 46.15560425283834, 4.431770589521594 ], [ 46.16791483778646, 4.439193639737003 ], [ 46.16998904853596, 4.435772060175736 ], [ 46.18010788550735, 4.414915433192237 ], [ 46.18156481929947, 4.411150008217347 ], [ 46.18227866102438, 4.406966209179808 ], [ 46.18456671088968, 4.403509174410789 ], [ 46.18925424643544, 4.396783755671023 ], [ 46.19570191957066, 4.39747939068123 ], [ 46.20316836045577, 4.423571836902974 ], [ 46.20706171749928, 4.422359640985007 ], [ 46.21010077361071, 4.420471659265854 ], [ 46.21965844746768, 4.407356367902624 ], [ 46.21982737938801, 4.388683312501862 ], [ 46.22571105646608, 4.386829907900418 ], [ 46.23755075963317, 4.39209447339758 ], [ 46.24354546160409, 4.388785758384324 ], [ 46.24619830411654, 4.386173183144986 ], [ 46.24794900440396, 4.38889827660288 ], [ 46.2643415894465, 4.393582057210332 ], [ 46.26655827183746, 4.397449686073675 ], [ 46.27187809126278, 4.397064201352286 ], [ 46.27457798360896, 4.396974174839016 ], [ 46.28435539290889, 4.399371429518632 ], [ 46.29277972056357, 4.407707294944299 ], [ 46.29609636649197, 4.406422030172297 ], [ 46.29537513021594, 4.411216732267508 ], [ 46.29633635905063, 4.424994132856644 ], [ 46.30286120593534, 4.427650449880751 ], [ 46.29631496657498, 4.438330372797787 ], [ 46.29309133554136, 4.440062626728649 ], [ 46.29647617285935, 4.453855067913997 ], [ 46.29405157990985, 4.46279605745037 ], [ 46.28443417433566, 4.47602647504644 ], [ 46.28709961733546, 4.484382424854218 ], [ 46.28803138168911, 4.489069361733742 ], [ 46.27010728719618, 4.50209226866315 ], [ 46.26716933623024, 4.504596974106646 ], [ 46.2719961499778, 4.542944499553459 ], [ 46.27395480446275, 4.547049893978835 ], [ 46.2832619806662, 4.548685286189365 ], [ 46.29129615541792, 4.556044471210963 ], [ 46.29402942721709, 4.55844617134213 ], [ 46.29306430926767, 4.570871194910193 ], [ 46.29001185910924, 4.572758405594865 ], [ 46.27707566137231, 4.573323169325609 ], [ 46.27025349602457, 4.58326888257721 ], [ 46.26839674289919, 4.587119484978682 ], [ 46.26643179980633, 4.615050419767011 ], [ 46.2654086056003, 4.617672483965549 ], [ 45.80592709186426, 4.865072663474678 ], [ 45.80434184846744, 4.864499321786514 ], [ 45.80433950695036, 4.864498347340356 ], [ 45.80545594864911, 4.848595888972264 ], [ 45.76435319429793, 4.801430760920382 ], [ 45.71917418711324, 4.781774751613478 ], [ 45.68363470756887, 4.80870542554455 ], [ 45.80122758057101, 4.376352681950241 ] ]', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue', 'operationTime': Timestamp(1611827959, 1), '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1611827959, 1), 'signature': {'hash': b'\x8d\xb6\x9b7\x0b\xe7!\x11\xe6\xc1\x13\x06\xf4\xe0\xca\xfe\xcbN\x0cy', 'keyId': 6872375198939611144}}}
```

Comment: Does your `polygon.json` have any co ordinates?

Comment: Yes, they appear in the error above. The code works normally so this particular polygon has a problem. When seen in qgis it looks like a normal connected polygon without holes.